# Merge one specific PDF file with each PDF file in a folder

Tags: pdf, merge

I have a large number of sequentially-named scanned files in one folder, and another single PDF file containing a message for recipients in another folder.

I need to merge the message PDF into each scanned file.  Each resulting file will retain the original scanned-file name. For example, the collection of files is:

```
message.pdf
001.pdf
002.pdf
003.pdf
etc.
```

After merging, the contents would be this:

```
001.pdf= message.pdf+001.pdf
002.pdf= message.pdf+002.pdf
003.pdf= message.pdf+003.pdf
etc.
```

Can this be done in an automated way in either Windows 8.1 or Ubuntu?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  Some type of matching specific source and destination files?  Merge all PDF files into a single file?  What does "not all together" mean?  Isn't that the meaning of merge?  If you are merging many, named by barcode, into one, how does it get "the" original name (which one)?

Comment: thanks for asking, I do not intend to merge all files together. Let's say a have a group of files 001.pdf, 002.pdf, 003.pdf and one single file letter.pdf. I want to merge letter.pdf with 001.pdf into 001.pdf, letter.pdf with 002.pdf into 002.pdf and letter.pdf with 003.pdf into 003.pdf.

Comment: In fact I want to prepend letter.pdf to each file from the group.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 8.1 but Ubuntu would be possible to use as well.